# spiral slide with geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I'm trying to make a spiral slide with geometry nodes.

I've been able to do what I want with *Instance on Points*, but I cannot find a way to extrude from each instance or similar. I've used *Align to Euler* to achieve the arc pointing downwards.

It seems I should use  *Curve to Mesh*, but then I cannot use the Euler approach.

I've made an example to visually show how far I am so far.
I'm on Blender 3.2.1

[image]

Comment: Why not use *Curve to Mesh* directly on the curve you are instancing over instead, using a semi-circle section?

Comment: When using the Curve to Mesh on the Spiral I can't control the rotation, at least not with what I know about geonodes.

Comment: You don't need to,  *Curve to Mesh*  always orients your profile perpendicularly to the curve without manual intervention

Comment: It might be that I don't understand fully.. but when I use Curve to Mesh, it rotates like this: https://media.giphy.com/media/Yu9FkLqNqVoDBbsw7t/giphy.gif

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/veLP0yy simplified geo node example for clarification :)

Comment: Sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), that is probably what you should have been asking about in the first place. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49265/how-to-edit-curve-but-not-ruined-tilt-settings/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/object-on-curve-wont-stay-flat/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35771/why-does-a-bezier-curve-twist-when-rotated

Comment: What you need to use here is the `set curve tilt` node. However, still struggling myself on where to pull the correct tilt from, as this has to be procedurally modified along the spiral curve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To align the tilt of the curve upwards, you can use the following node setup:

[image]

This calculates an angle from the values for normals, curve tangents and the up vector, which is plugged directly into the node `Set Curve Tilt`.

[image]

Comment: how did you figure out the formula on how to calculate the tilt?

Comment: Looking forward to trying this! Have left my computer for today but will try tomorrow - and yes, how did you get to this beautiful formula? Usually I can mess around and fond a suitable solution, but this is above my head 

Comment: nothing but amazing - thanks!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

You can get over the tilt problem by constructing the spiral in the flat, capturing the spiral's *Parameter* or *Length*, converting to a mesh, and *then* setting the height as a function of the captured attribute:

[image]

Comment: Or... you can [do it properly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/271090/35559) :)