# How to align planes to curve spiral in geonodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, normals, instances

I am trying to align the incline of instanced planes to the spiral curve they are instanced on. As you can see in my current setup the alignment on the x and y axis sort of flips part way through the spiral. is there a way to correct this so the planes follow the spirals tangent upwards but don´t flip?
In the second image you can see my basic setup for this.
In the third image i've tried to solve it with a profile curve but the spiral sort of curls inwards. is there a way to prevent this?
Thank you guys in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271084/spiral-slide-with-geo-nodes/

Comment: And of course you could use the node `Set Curve Normals` (Blender 3.4+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a set curve normal set to Z up before the curve to mesh as pointed out by quellenform.

[image]
[image]

Additionally if you need the curve to be flipped on its side, just flip the width and height values of your profile curve to get the desired effect.

[image]
[image]